# Picasa bulk upload without local install

Tags: browser-addons, picasa, portable-apps

I'd like to upload pictures to Picasa without installing the full client locally.

Is there a FireFox or IE extension or add-on I can install to do this?

Is there a portable version I can install on a flash drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Universal Uploader (fireuploader) for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4724/)

> Here is list of all sites supported by Fireuploader...
>
> - **Picasa**
> - Rapidshare
> - Photobucket
> - Mosso
> - Box.net
> - Flickr
> - Youtube
> - Facebook
> - Webshots
> - Omnidrive
> - Smugmug
> - SmeStorage
> - Google Docs
> - Snaphappi, a digital photo processing website
> - Adobe Share
> - Slideshare